# How to delete multiple items using Ajax in Java Spring Boot MVC

Tags: java, ajax, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I'm trying to delete multiple items in my table by using a checkbox and a delete button. I've tried searching how to do this in different forums but can see the solution. This is my last resort.

This is my Ajax Code:

```
  $('#delete').on('click', function(e){
        // For selecting data in tables
           var selected = []; // for getting the checkbox value
           $('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function() {
               if ($(this).get(0).checked) {
                   selected.push($(this).attr('value'));
               }
           }); 
           var formData = new FormData();
                    formData.append("assetID", selected);
                    $.ajax({ 
                        url: "delete-asset", 
                        type: "POST", 
                        data: formData,
                        dataType: 'JSON',
                        enctype : 'multipart/form-data', 
                        processData : false,
                        contentType : false,
                        success : function(data) {
                             if (data.status == 1) {
                                openAlertDialog("Success", data.message, "Continue","manage-assets");
                            } else {
                                openAlertDialog("Error", data.message, "Continue", "manage-assets");
                            } 
                         },
                         error : function(data) {
                                openAlertDialog("Error", data.message, "Continue", "manage-assets");
                        },
            });
       });
```

This is my controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/delete-asset", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String deleteAsset(@ModelAttribute AssetCategory assetCategory) {

    JsonObject result = new JsonObject();
    assetService.deleteAssetByID(assetCategory.getAssetID());
    result.addProperty("result", "Success");
    result.addProperty("status", 1);
    result.addProperty("message", "Asset Deleted!");
    return "result.toString()";
}
```

Right now I'm trying to delete one item before proceeding to delete multiple items. I'm having an error 405 and can't proceed due to this problem.

Comment: Have to tried to narrow down the cause ? Can you use Postman or Curl to try only your controller ?

Comment: I don't know how to use postman or curl. I'll read the tutorial and  try. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just write this.value you should get the value of the checked item.

try this code to fetch all items.

```
var selectedItem = new Array();
$('input[name="Item"]:checked').each(function() {
selectedItem.push(this.value);
});
```

Before sending the data stored in array to controller, just try to alert the data to see if its working or not,

I hope this will work

Comment: This worked. And I changed my controller to accept Array values. Thanks!